# Windows FTP functions [C]

Tags: c, function, ftp

Does anyone know a function/library that I could use to do general FTP functions in a FTP connection?

I'd rather have these in C, as that would be extremely easy to add to my current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched wininet on MSDN [which I should have done in the first place] and I managed to find this list of functions, some of which are HTTP, and some exclusively for FTP.
[MSDN Wininet Function Ref.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385473%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Good luck using WinInet when you ever decide to port your program to Linux or another non-Windows OS.

Comment: True, however the application for me is just a little quick and dirty application. Nothing I'm planning on releasing.

Answer (score 2):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is probably the best library you can use for that.